# Generating QVD files from pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, qlikview

I want to generate qlikview qvd files from pandas dataframes with python. There exists a qvd decoder in python (https://github.com/BenSimonds/Qlik-Script-Tools/), but I am intrested in a qvd encoder.

Answer (score 1):

I havent seen a way to generate `qvd` files (at least not open sourced). Qlik understand another format similar to `qvd` - `qvx` (QlikView data eXchange).

Havent seen as well much of a tools that generate `qvx` files but at least there is some (older) documentation that can be found.

[This link](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Documents/QlikView-QVX-File-Format/ta-p/1484976) will lead you to a Qlik Community post that have something on the topic + a PDF with `qvx` specs

[This link](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview-developer/November2017/Subsystems/QVXSDKAPI/Content/QlikView%20QVX%20File%20Format/QVX-file-format1.htm) is from Qlik's help page (which might overlap with the pdf doc)

Also someone started `Node` project few years ago that can generate `qvx` files (it might help you) https://github.com/kmpm/node-qvx

Answer (score 1):

The best/quickest way is to save your Pandas as CSV.
Then in QlikView/QlikSense script LOAD it and then

```
STORE Table into file.qvd (qvd);
```

I've tried some non qlikview qvd libraries and they are good only in read files, when I used them to save qvd I often got files corrupted, so better just use qlikview script.